# Change color every other row with $.each

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, loops

I am making a golf leaderboard and want to change the color on every other row to be slightly grey... How do I do that?

Here is how I get the leaderboard using ajax:

```
$.get("http://mypage.com/json/getleaderboard.php", function(data) {

    var output = '';

    output += '<li class="leaderboard-head"><span class="leaderboard-head-placement">&nbsp;</span><span class="leaderboard-name tr" key="name">Name</span><span class="leaderboard-head-points">P</span></li>';

    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        output += '<li><span class="leaderboard-placement">' + val.placement + '</span><span class="leaderboard-name">' + val.name + '</span><span class="leaderboard-points">' + val.points + '</span></li>';
    });


    $('#leaderboardList').append(output).listview('refresh');

}, "json");
```

hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the nth-child selector. e.g.

```
<ul class="leaderboard">
<li class="leaderboard-head">1</li>
<li class="leaderboard-head">2</li>
<li class="leaderboard-head">3</li>
<li class="leaderboard-head">4</li>
<li class="leaderboard-head">5</li>
<li class="leaderboard-head">6</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.leaderboard-head:nth-child(odd){            // Odd/Even according to your requirements
 background-color: gray;
}
```

Note that this will only work in CSS3 compatible browsers. For others you can use :

```
$(".leaderboard").children(":nth-child(odd)").each(function(){    // Odd/Even according to your requirements
    $(this).css("background", "gray");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VJREW/1/)

You can remove the css/jquery and it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you use CSS and do (assuming there is a class `leaderboard-entry`):

```
li.leaderboard-entry {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

li.leaderboard-entry:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #afafaf;
}
```

No JavaScript required.

---

On a more general note, your code should read

```
$.get("http://mypage.com/json/getleaderboard.php")
.done(function(data) {
    $('<li class="leaderboard-head">' + 
        '<span class="leaderboard-head-placement">&nbsp;</span>' +
        '<span class="leaderboard-name tr" key="name">Name</span>' +
        '<span class="leaderboard-head-points">P</span>' + 
      '</li>'
    ).appendTo('#leaderboardList');

    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        $('<li class="leaderboard-entry">')
        .append($('<span class="leaderboard-placement">', {text: val.placement})) 
        .append($('<span class="leaderboard-name">', {text: val.name}))
        .append($('<span class="leaderboard-points">', {text: val.points}))
        .appendTo('#leaderboardList');
    });

    $('#leaderboardList').listview('refresh');
});
```

Don't create HTML by concatenating arbitrary strings. This is the single source of cross site scripting vulnerabilities (and blown markup).

Also, declaring the request type (`"json"`) in jQuery is superfluous if the server sends JSON and sets the correct `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

if you sway to do using jquery rather than css (good one)

```
$.get("http://mypage.com/json/getleaderboard.php", function(data) {

        var output = '';

        output += '<li class="leaderboard-head"><span class="leaderboard-head-placement">&nbsp;</span><span class="leaderboard-name tr" key="name">Name</span><span class="leaderboard-head-points">P</span></li>';

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        var color_style_class = 'blue';
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            color_style_class = 'green';
        }
        else
        {
            color_style_class = 'red';
        }
            output += '<li><span class="leaderboard-placement ' + color_style_class + '">' + val.placement + '</span><span class="leaderboard-name">' + val.name + '</span><span class="leaderboard-points">' + val.points + '</span></li>';
        });


        $('#leaderboardList').append(output).listview('refresh');

    }, "json");
```

define new style for 'blue' , 'green' and 'red' or whatever you like